# AWS CloudFormation template: using conditions to scope

Tags: amazon-web-services, conditional-statements, aws-cloudformation

I am attempting to use conditions to scope a resource in a CloudFormation template but am having no luck. I attempted to use "Deny: NotPrincipal" as shown below but that action is not allowed due to an error "Policy document should not specify a principal".  Any suggestions on how to scope ec2:CopyImage to only a specific role would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
        {
          "Sid": "DenyCopyAMI",
          "Effect": "Deny",
          "NotPrincipal": {
            "AWS": [
              "arn:aws:sts::*:assumed-role/EngineeringRole/*",
              "arn:aws:sts::*:assumed-role/PlatformRole/*",
              "arn:aws:iam::*:role/EngineeringRole/*",
              "arn:aws:iam::*:role/PlatformRole/*"
            ]
          },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an article from AWS on [restricting access to a role](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/).

use [iam get-role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-role.html) to find the `RoleId` and add it to the policy condition under `aws:userId`

```
aws iam get-role --role-name Test-Role
```

IAM policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "ec2:CopyImage",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:userId": [
                        "AROAJPXXXXXJE5XOMQARS:*",
                        "AROAJPXXXXXJE5XOMQARS:*",
                        "AROAJXXXXXXV3EZVH2W5A:*",
                        "AROAJXXXXXXBH4XK552KI:*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Excellent.. thank you. I think this is exactly what I was looking for. I'll give it a shot and report back.